# getting out of memory error

Tags: java, android

I am trying to load a 12mb txt file into memory as a HashMap to make it available for the application to use it but I am getting an OutOfMemoryError

```
09-27 15:42:17.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19030):     ... 11 more
09-27 15:42:17.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19030): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
09-27 15:42:17.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19030):     at java.util.HashMap.makeTable(HashMap.java:559)
09-27 15:42:17.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19030):     at java.util.HashMap.doubleCapacity(HashMap.java:579)
09-27 15:42:17.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19030):     at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:409)
09-27 15:42:17.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19030):     at org.com.SentencesActivity.loadBigramFrequencies(SentencesActivity.java:151)
09-27 15:42:17.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19030):     at org.com.SentencesActivity.onClick(SentencesActivity.java:56)
```

Is there any way to solve it or it is a limitation of dalvik vm?

Code for loading the file into memory:

```
public HashMap<String, Double> loadBigramFrequencies() throws IOException {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

        HashMap<String, Double> bigramFrequencies = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        String[] splittedLine;
        try {
            // open the file for reading
            InputStream instream = assetManager.open("bigramFrequencies.txt");

            // if file the available for reading
            if (instream != null) {
                // prepare the file for reading
                InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
                BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

                String line;

                // read every line of the file into the line-variable, on line
                // at the time
                while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // do something with the settings from the file
                    splittedLine = line.split("\\#");
                    bigramFrequencies.put(splittedLine[0].trim(),
                            Double.parseDouble(splittedLine[1].trim()));
                }
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "bigram frequencies loaded");

            }

            // close the file again
            instream.close();

        } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
            // do something if the myfilename.txt does not exits
        }

        return bigramFrequencies;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please either post the full source code of this example, or preferably a smaller, simpler reproduction of this issue? Either post to the question or, if very verbose, onto pastebin. Thanks!

Comment: What's your code to load the txt file into memory? First off, 12MB is HUGE to begin with, and then you are trying to make a data structure out of it. See if there isn't a way to either shrink the text file or load it in incrementally or something :)

Comment: 12mb is huge on a server, let alone on a mobile device.  I presume it's a digram dictionary for sentence analysis?  Can you not host it online behind a service architecture?

Answer (score 2):

Reading a 12mb file in memory will slow down the device. 12mb might sound less for a normal pc, but most Android phones come with less then 512MB of RAM.

You should be able to reformat the file or split it up so the application can read the necessary parts when it needs them.

Also, using a [SQLite Database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) might be better suited an speed up the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

A `HashMap` in the application had an item added to it, and in doing so hit its limit for the current array backing.  So, it attempted to resize and in doing so it ran out of memory.

HashMaps use hashes to jump to a particular element in an array, then it looks for the item in the backing store.  The entire algorithm depends heavily on the array being sparse enough to avoid excessive collision of the hash space (the hash divided modulus by the array size).  If you add a lot to a hash oriented structure, it needs to allocate a bigger array to maintain enough empty array elements for the performance to not degrade horribly.

After the allocation of the new array, each element from the old array is relocated into the new array.  This effectively adds "empty slots" for other items to utilize.

Answer (score 1):

If device has adequate Memory then

Try increasing the heap size available to app.

Edit the build.prop file and increase the heap size

dalvik.vm.heapsize=32m